# Remove strings that contain another existing string in a list of strings

Tags: python, list, substring

I want to remove the strings that contain another existing string in a list of strings.
Suppose that I have a list as below:

```
ex_list = ['transport truck', 'truck', 'plastic boat', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry', 'truck parking', 'pickup truck', 'pickup']
```

I want to remove some specific string like **transport truck** because it is a kind of **truck** and so on.

My desire output:

```
new_list = ['truck', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry', 'truck parking', 'pickup']
```

In this result note that I want to keep **truck parking** because it is not part of the **truck** so here I want to remove the prefix string (i.e. sth + truck) not the suffix string (truck + sth).

What I have tried so far:

```
def contains_word(s, w):
    return f' {w} ' in f' {s} '

new_list = []
for i in ex_list:
    if len(i.split(' '))== 1:
        new_list.append(i)
        
remain_list = list(set(ex_list) - set(new_list))
for i in new_list:
    for j in remain_list:
        if not contains_word(i, j):
            new_list.append(i)
```

I think that the first loop worked well but the second loop did not work. What happened in the second loop (It ran for so long so i stopped it)? Are there any other solutions?

Thanks in advance for the correction.

Comment: your `ex_list` is not quite representative, with the 1st for loop you will already get the desired result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, in this case, yes, but that's just a poor explanation by OP of what they actually want to accomplish. It wouldn't be a general solution to OP's problem.

Comment: @JacobIvanov, that's why I asked for a more representative input

Comment: @JacobIvanov Updated list. Can you please check your codes again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list to store the suffixes that have already been seen, and as long as you build it in increasing length of expressions, you can safely check that ending of subsequent expressions is not already in the seen list.

```
ex_list = ['transport truck', 'truck', 'plastic boat', 'boat', 'transport',
           'ferry', 'truck parking', 'pickup truck', 'pickup', 
           'dump truck parking', 'red fire truck']

seen = list()
keep = {ex for ex in sorted(ex_list,key=len)
           if not any(map(ex.endswith,seen))
           and not seen.append(" "+ex)}
```

By processing the expression in order of length, any expression ending with another one will be checked after including all shorter expressions. Expressions can only include shorter expressions, so all possible overlaps will have already been processed.)

output:

```
print(keep)
{'ferry', 'boat', 'pickup', 'truck', 'truck parking', 'transport'}
```

If you want them in the original order, you can use the `keep` set to filter the original list:

```
print([ex for ex in ex_list if ex in keep])
['truck', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry', 'truck parking', 'pickup']
```

You could also write this in a more straightforward (albeit less efficient) way by matching each item to all the others:

```
ex_list = [ex for ex in ex_list 
           if not any(ex.endswith(" "+suffix) for suffix in ex_list)]

print(ex_list)
['truck', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry', 'truck parking', 'pickup']
```

Comment: Updated the input list to get a more representative list.

Comment: Adjusted answer to exclude prefixes only.  Would you also have cases where multi-word suffixes would need to be taken into account ? such as ['truck parking', 'dump truck parking']

Comment: Yes for sure. It can be the case.

Comment: Adjusted answer for multi-word prefixes and suffixes

Answer (score 0):

The following is what you want:

```py
ex_list = ['transport truck', 'truck', 'plastic boat', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry']

def contains_word(s, w):
    return f' {w} ' in f' {s} '

new_list = []
for i in ex_list:
   if len(i.split(' ')) == 1:
      new_list.append(i)

remain_list = list(set(ex_list) - set(new_list))

for s in remain_list:
   sub_words = s.split(' ')
   for w in sub_words[1::]: 
      # [1::] can be removed, if you want 'plastic' to be included in `new_list`
      if w not in new_list:
          new_list.append(w)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['truck', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry']
```

Comment: Updated the input list. Please check.

Comment: @Erwin, in order to do this with the updated list, I would need a better understanding of the logic behind keeping 'truck parking'.

Comment: 'truck parking' in this case is the parking slots for the truck and not a truck itself which is different from for example transport truck is a kind of a truck.

Answer (score 0):

The second loop doesn't work because you keep adding elements into new_list while looping through it, which makes it never stop. You can resolve this by changing your strategy from adding to removing.

As @RomanPerekhrest said, we need a more representative ex_list to know what kind of solution you want. Assuming you just want to get rid of all elements containing any other elements, One Solution is:

```
ex_list = ['transport truck', 'truck', 'plastic boat', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry', 'extra test']
        
remain_list = ex_list.copy()

for i in ex_list:
    for j in remain_list:
        if i != j and i.endswith(j):
            remain_list.remove(i)
            break
```

This will give you:

```
['truck', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry', 'truck parking', 'pickup']
```

With the original order of elements.

Comment: Updated the list to get a more representative input.

Comment: @Erwin this actually makes it easier, you don't need contains_word() and use String.endswith() instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
ex_list = ['transport truck', 'truck', 'plastic boat', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry']

one_word_list = [x for x in ex_list if ' ' not in x]

remain_list = [*one_word_list]  # Fills list with single-word strings

# Loop over all strings. For multi-word strings, if either word is in one_word_list, do not append to remain_list
for x in ex_list:
    valid_word = True
    word_list = x.split(' ')
    for word in word_list:
        if word in one_word_list:
            valid_word = False
            
    if valid_word:
        remain_list.append(x)
```

Output:

```
['truck', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry']
```

Answer (score 0):

with the code like that, you have an infinite loop, cause 'new_list' keeps growing.. Try with a list comprehension like this:

```js
// this is optional, use if you want to preserve the words order

           from collections import OrderedDict

            ex_list = ['transport truck', 'truck', 'plastic boat', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry']

            // Create OrderedDict with words to remove, if order does not matter use remove_set = set()

            remove_dict = OrderedDict()
            for i in ex_list:
                for j in ex_list:
                    if i != j and contains_word(i, j):
                        
                        // if you use remove_set then use remove_set.add(i)
                        remove_dict[i] = None

            // here you have the list of remaining words, same here if you used remove_set change the remove_dict for remove_set

            new_list = [x for x in ex_list if x not in remove_dict]

            print(new_list)  // ['truck', 'boat', 'transport', 'ferry']
```

Comment: Updated the input list to get a more representative list.